# Does System Update also update the OS?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, updates, update-manager

If I update my Ubuntu 12.04 through Update Manager, does it update to the Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends upon the settings in Update Manager.

While in the Update Manager application, select the `Settings` button.
Under the `Update` tab, there will be a field labelled `Notify me of new updates`.

You will have three options to choose from:

1. Never
2. For long term support versions
3. For any new version

If you are running 12.04 and have option 2 selected, you will not be prompted to upgrade to 12.10(or later). With Option 3 selected, Update Manager will offer you the ability to upgrade to 12.10.

By selecting option 1, you will only be prompted for security updates and the latest package upgrades for your distribution(in this case 12.04)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know the existence of such an option.

Answer (score 0):

No, it gives latest security updates and latest packages.

Comment: Yes, that's the default setting. If it is changed to get latest version updates, it will.

Answer (score 0):

It does if you tell it to. But seeing as 12.04 is an LTS release, you have to enable the option in the update manager's properties, I believe.

Comment: Yes, I've select For any new version to get latest OS update.

Answer (score 0):

yes it does if you check the option to do it .Otherwise it will only do security updates and other bug fixes.